# Printer.js not printing to console

Tags: javascript, node.js

So for some reason all of a sudden after I move my print functions to their own file and try to run the node command on my app.js file then it doesn't want to print anything in my console. Why is that?

I am still struggling with debugging this one as nothing is printing out when I run the following command.

```
node app.js myusernamehere
```

Anyone have any idea?

**app.js**

```
var profile = require("./profile.js");
var users = process.argv.slice(2);

users.forEach(profile.get);
```

**profile.js**

```
//Problem: We need a simple way to look at a user's badge count and Javascript points
//Solution: Use Node.js to connect to Treehouse's API to get profile information to print out
var https = require("https");
var http = require("http");
var printer = require("./printer.js");

function get(username) {
    //Connect to API URL (http://teamtreehouse.com/username.json)
    var request = https.get("https://teamtreehouse.com/" + username + ".json", function(response) {
        var body = "";
        //Read the data
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                try {
                    //Parse the data
                    var profile = JSON.parse(body);
                    //Print the data
                    printer.printMessage(username, profile.badges.length, profile.points.JavaScript);
                } catch(error) {
                    //Parse Error
                    printer.printError(error);
                }
            } else {
                //Status Code Error
                printer.printError({message: "There was an error getting the profile for " + username + ".  (" + http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode] + ")"});
            }
        });
    });

    //Connection Error
    request.on('error', printer.printError);
}

module.exports.get = get;
```

**printer.js**

```
//Print out message
function printMessage(username, badgeCount, points) {
    var message = username + " has " + badgeCount + " total badge(s) and " + points + " points in Javascript";
    console.log(message);
}

//Print out error messages
function printError(error) {
    console.error(error.message);
}

module.exports.printMessage = printMessage;
module.exports.printError = printError;
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on why nothing is printing out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what actually happened but it works now and nothing in my code was changed.