# Undefined forEach TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm putting together a nodejs application to retrieve my awards stuff from a website I frequent and having an issue with getting it to work. I'm trying to find out how I can pass the topic variable as an argument to my profile.get function.

**Attempted the following:**

```
users.forEach(profile.get(topic));
```

**Result:**

```
users.forEach(profile.get(topic));
      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

**app.js**

```
var profile = require("./profile.js");
var topic = process.argv.slice(2,3);
var users = process.argv.slice(3);

users.forEach(profile.get);
```

**profile.js**

```
function get(username, topic) {
    //Connect to API URL (http://url.com/username.json)
    var request = https.get("https://url.com/" + username + ".json", function(response) {
        var body = "";
        //Read the data
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                try {
                    //Parse the data
                    var profile = JSON.parse(body);
                    //Print the data
                    printer.printMessage(username, profile.badges.length, profile.points.topic, topic);
                } catch(error) {
                    //Parse Error
                    printer.printError(error);
                }
            } else {
                //Status Code Error
                printer.printError({message: "There was an error getting the profile for " + username + ".  (" + http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode] + ")"});
            }
        });
    });

    //Connection Error
    request.on('error', printer.printError);
}
```

Update:

console.log(users);

returns [ 'myuserrname', 'secondusernamehere' ]

Comment: You have to wrap that call in a function, because you need to pass a function to `.forEach()`. It's unclear exactly what the code should look like because it's unclear what's in the `users` array and how its contents relate to the calls to that `profile.get()` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `users` contains the user names to be passed to that `.get()` function, then your loop would look like this:

```
users.forEach(function(username) {
  profile.get(username, topic);
});
```

The `.forEach()` method invokes your callback function, passing in succession each value in the array. If the values are the usernames, then each invocation of your callback will give you one username. Assuming that the `topic` value is something defined outside the code you posted, it will be visible inside the callback too.

In your attempt, you were directly calling `profile.get()` and passing its *return* value to `.forEach()`. The function has no return value, so that's why `.forEach()` threw that exception — the callback value you passed was `undefined`.

In [your previous question about this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673382/printer-js-not-printing-to-console/35702460#35702460), you were working with a version of that `.get()` function that only took one parameter. Because of that, using

```
users.forEach(profile.get);
```

worked fine, because you passed a *reference* to the `.get()` function to `.forEach()`, and so it worked. However in this code:

```
users.forEach(profile.get(topic));
```

that `profile.get(topic)` is a *call* to the function. That's what caused the problem. In JavaScript, the way to get around an issue like that (at least, the simplest immediate way) is to introduce that wrapper function at the top of this answer. Now, `.forEach()` is happy, because you're passing it a function to call, and `profile.get()` is happy because you're passing both the parameters it expects.

Comment: Yes, maybe an explanation about why it wasn't working for him would also help? `profile.get` for example would need to return a function.

Comment: It works the old way before I decided to add in a topic so I wouldn't have to pass in the username into the forEach I could just call it and it would know it..

Comment: @user3732216 you don't pass the username into the `.forEach()` call; `.forEach()` passes the username into *your* function.

Comment: @Pointy check out this stack question I did yesterday I didn't have to pass in username and it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673382/printer-js-not-printing-to-console/35702460#35702460 so how can I get the topic passed.

Comment: @user3732216 that works because you only had one parameter in that version. Now that you have to pass in that `topic` parameter, you need to adapt the API that `.forEach()` expects to the API that you've actually got.

Comment: @user3732216 I'll put that explanation in the answer; hold on.

Comment: I very much like your updated response. Very informational. However I run that same command I was attempting in my post and it returns an undefined for the topic for the returned string so I go into the get function in my profile.js file and console.log the topic inside the function and I get 1 I believe. So I'm not sure how I can get that if I'm passing in a value of lets say Javascript.

Comment: Well in your original question, it looks like `topic` is set before you call `.forEach()`. Have you tried adding a `console.log("User: " + username + " topic: " + topic);` to the top of `profile.get()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104887/discussion-between-user3732216-and-pointy).